# When I include url on a line, it shows up left-justified instead of centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, urls

If I use the `url` package and include a url on a line inside the `centering` environment, it shows up left-justified instead of centered.  How can I make it centered?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbers 

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\par My Name
\par My Department
\par My Department But With More Words
\par My department's Address
\par My phone number and e-mail address
\par Website: \url{http://my.web.site/}
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting of a paragraph is done when encountering a `\par` (or empty line). Adding `\par` to the last line provides the appropriate horizontal alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbers 

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
My Name \par
My Department \par
My Department But With More Words \par
My department's Address \par
My phone number and e-mail address \par
Website: \url{http://my.web.site/}\par
\end{centering}

\end{document}​
```

As such, your initial `\par` has no effect. Of course, there are other ways of obtaining this output as well:

```
\begin{center}
  My Name \\
  My Department \\
  My Department But With More Words \\
  My department's Address \\
  My phone number and e-mail address \\
  Website: \url{http://my.web.site/}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\centering` is not designed to be used as an environment. As @Werner noted it does not center the last paragraph if used without an explicit paragraph end. Use `center` instead of `centering`. The problem is unrelated to `\url` you would see the same effect with plain text.